# Issue resizing website window to mobile size using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I'm trying to set a scaleable window using Bootstrap, the padding of my elements changes the scaling, the the website does not properly scale to the mobile size. I cannot find out how to fix this.

my HTML is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, inital-scale=1.0">
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:200' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="no.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>





    <header>
        <div class="navbar navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">

            <a href="#" class="logo"></a>
                <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom" role="navigation">

                <button class = "navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = ".navHeaderCollapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

              <li><a href="yes.html">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="team.html">The Team</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Event Schedule</a></li>
          <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>

              </ul>

               </div>      

                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>

    </header>


        <section>




    <div class="container">





        <div class="row">


        <div class="who">


            <h2>Who Are We?</h2>
        <p>YES is an organization founded by youth for youth to help make a positive change within society. By supporting a large variety of organizations both big and small within the community, youth not only get the opportunity to explore their interests, but are able to gain a voice in society. If you are interested, our weekly meetings will begin in 2015.</p>





        </div>



        </div>

    <div class="row">


        <div class="why">


         <h2>Why YES?</h2>
    <p>We strive to provide youth (anywhere within Peel) with new experiences, help youth explore their interests, provide opportunities for them to socialize with other youth and provide them with activities to do which will help them in gaining volunteer hours. We will most likely have weekly meetings where we will discuss issues regarding a specific topic, which will be different every month! We will work together to create awareness about these topics by doing activities related to the topic and fundraising for an organization that supports or represents the topic. YES is a great way to gain your 40 hours and get exposure to many amazing organizations and activities!</p>

        </div>
    </div>



        <div class="row">

        <div class="update">


            <h2>Updates</h2>
            <p>Youth Engagement in Peel is a new orgination, as a result of which, the first meeting is scheduled to occur sometime in February. Voting will be posted on the "Event Schedule" page, and the topic will be updated on a month-to-month basis. Please check back for more information.</p>












            </div>








        </div>
        </div>


















    <footer>


                  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom navbar-fixed-bottom"> 
                      <div class="copy">
            <img src=img/facebook.png>
            <img src="img/twitter-wrap.png">
        <p>&copy;Youth Engagement in Society. All Rights Reserved</p>
                      </div>


        </div>
            </footer>
    </section>
</body>
```

And my CSS is

```
    body {
    background-color: #e8e8e8;

}

header {

    padding: 7px;
    background-color: white;
}

header img {

    text-align: center;
    height: 60px;
    width: 200px;
}



/* Navigation Bar */




.navbar-custom {
    color: white;
    background-color: white;
    border-color: white;
    margin-top:0px;

} 


navbar-inverse .navbar-brand { color: red;}

.navbar a {
  color: black;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

.navbar li {

    display: inline;

}



/* Paragraphs and images*/


.who {
    width: 600px;
    margin-top:100px;
}   

.why {
    margin-top:100px;
    margin-left: 500px;
}   

.update {
    margin-top:100px;
    width: 600px;
}   


/* Footer */

footer {
    margin-top: 550px;
    background-color: #4f4f4f;
    clear: both;

}

footer p {
    color: black;

    padding-left: 200px;
}

.copy p {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: You are using bootstrap on the wrong way ... follow some tuto and you will understand

Comment: how can I position the paragraph without using fixed width?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.col-xs-*` `.col-sm-*` `.col-md-*` `.col-lg-*` inside `.row` class if you want to use bootstrap responvie block classes

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">column1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">column2</div>
</div>
```

watch some examples 
http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options

Comment: even when I use the "col-md-6", the scaling is quite a bit off compared to the navbar

Comment: @VibhasVatve bootstrap doesn't "scale" your content don't use fixed widths or such far margin and padding .... avoid margins.

Comment: Im a beginner at coding sorry. So how would I make it responsive if I want a paragraph element to only occupy a certain width in the column without the use of fixed widths or margin or padding